# PHP read Netlist from txt file

Tags: php, arrays, strpos

I have this file format of txt file generated from schematic software:

```
(
NETR5_2
R6,1
R5,2
)
(
NETR1_2
R4,2
R3,1
R3,2
R2,1
R2,2
R1,1
R1,2
)
```

I need to get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => NETR5_2
        [1] => R6,1
        [2] => R5,2
    )
    [1] => Array
        [0] => NETR1_2
        [1] => R4,2
        [2] => R3,1
        [3] => R3,2
        [4] => R2,1
        [5] => R2,2
        [6] => R1,1
        [7] => R1,2
    )
```

Here is code i try but i get all from input string:

```
   $file = file('tangoLista.txt');

    /* GET - num of lines */
    $f = fopen('tangoLista.txt', 'rb');
    $lines = 0;

    while (!feof($f)) {
        $lines += substr_count(fread($f, 8192), "\n");
    }

    fclose($f);

     for ($i=0;$i<=$lines;$i++) {

        /* RESISTORS - check */
            if (strpos($file[$i-1], '(') !== false && strpos($file[$i], 'NETR') !== false) {

        /* GET - id */
            for($k=0;$k<=10;$k++) {
            if (strpos($file[$i+$k], ')') !== false || empty($file[$i+$k]))                    {
            } else {
                $json .= $k.' => '.$file[$i+$k];
            }
        }
        $resistors_netlist[] = array($json);
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($resistors_netlist);
echo '</pre>';
```

I need to read between ( and ) and put into array values...i try using checking if line begins with ( and NETR and if yes put into array...but i don't know how to get number if items between ( and ) to get foreach loop to read values and put into array.

Where i im making mistake? Can code be shorter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
<?php
$f = fopen('test.txt', 'rb');

$resistors_netlist = array();

$current_index = 0;
while (!feof($f)) {
    $line = trim(fgets($f));
    if (empty($line)) {
        continue;
    }

    if (strpos($line, '(') !== false) {
        $resistors_netlist[$current_index] = array();
        continue;
    }

    if (strpos($line, ')') !== false) {
        $current_index++;
        continue;
    }

    array_push($resistors_netlist[$current_index], $line);
}

fclose($f);

print_r($resistors_netlist);
```

This gives me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => NETR5_2
            [1] => R6,1
            [2] => R5,2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => NETR1_2
            [1] => R4,2
            [2] => R3,1
            [3] => R3,2
            [4] => R2,1
            [5] => R2,2
            [6] => R1,1
            [7] => R1,2
        )
)
```

We start `$current_index` at `0`. When we see a `(`, we create a new sub-array at `$resistors_netlist[$current_index]`. When we see a `)`, we increment `$current_index` by 1. For any other line, we just append it to the end of `$resistors_netlist[$current_index]`.

Comment: Thanks this works great....i im getting only this from php: Warning: array_push() [function.array-push]: First argument should be an array in line 42 but script is working perfect...thank you.

Comment: Awesome, no problem. I wasn't getting that with the dataset above; do you have an example that triggers that error? There might be something I overlooked.

Comment: i just turn off warnings in php ini file and all is ready to go...your code is simple clean and works..i try with multiple items in ( and ) and working excellent...now i need to add it to components from array and ready to go.

Comment: Awesome, well very glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using `preg_match_all`:

```php
$text = '(
NETR5_2
R6,1
R5,2
)
(
NETR1_2
R4,2
R3,1
R3,2
R2,1
R2,2
R1,1
R1,2
)';

$chunks = explode(")(", preg_replace('/\)\W+\(/m', ')(', $text));
$result = array();
$pattern = '{([A-z0-9,]+)}';

foreach ($chunks as $row) {
    preg_match_all($pattern, $row, $matches);
    $result[] = $matches[1];
}

print_r($result);
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/r3SF5)**</kbd>

I'm not the king of regex, so you can find a better way.
The main problem are parenthesis: I don't know what are between closing and next open parenthesis ( `)????(` ), so first I replace every space, tab, cr or ln between, then I explode the string by `)(`.

I perform a `foreach` loop for every element of resulted array, matching every occurrence of `A-z0-9,` and add array of retrieved values to an empty array that, at end of `foreach`, will contain desired result.

#### Please note:

The main pattern is based on provided example: if the values contains other characters then `A-z 0-9 ,` the regex fails.

#### Edit:

Replaced preliminar regex pattern with `/\)\W+\(/m`